# Easiest way to discover modules' APIs in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm comparing the developer experience between JavaScript and Java. While there are many things that are more "elegant" in JS, one thing I struggle with is figuring out how to use modules from npm.

For example, take morgan, the logging dependency for express. After some googling and looking at the docs, it's apparent that you can use it like this:

```
app.use(morgan('combined', { stream }));
```

IntelliJ helpfully hints the first parameter is 'format' and the second one is 'options'.

In Java, I would expect an enum for the standard definitions of format, and I would be able to figure out that stream is a property of the options object just by inspecting it in the IDE - not possible for morgan in this case since the source code just reads "arbitrary" properties of the supplied object.

Am I right in thinking that in the JS world, it's the docs or reading source code for cases such as this? Is there something I'm missing? My question is not specifically about morgan, this is just an example but I find myself running into this type of issue a lot as a beginner node user.

Comment: Docs, source code or [*types*](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/morgan), if the module has them.

Comment: Ever wonder why jetBrains has different IDE's for different languages?

Comment: @charlietfl IntelliJ ultimate has the [same support for JS as WebStorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html)

Comment: @CertainPerformance The original question also had a follow up asking why libraries don't implement enums/builders/etc to make them easier to use :) - but that has been removed now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I right in thinking that in the JS world, it's the docs or reading source code for cases such as this?

Often, yes. When you're wondering how a particular method should be used, usually the right approach is to look at the documentation for that method (like on MDN, or on the library's site or github). Sometimes, there are a couple other options available:

- The author of the library may have chosen to write their code using [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/), which can give elaborate descriptions and examples of how a method is meant to be used. [For example](https://jsdoc.app/tags-example.html), there may be something like:

  ```
  /**
  * Solves equations of the form a * x = b
  * @example
  * // returns 2
  * globalNS.method1(5, 10);
  * @example
  * // returns 3
  * globalNS.method(5, 15);
  * @returns {Number} Returns the value of x for the equation.
  */
  globalNS.method1 = function (a, b) {
      return b / a;
  };
  ```

  which will come up in a decent IDE when you have a reference to `method1` and try to use it.
- If the library supports TypeScript, or if someone or some people in the developer community have [written a TypeScript definition file](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped) for the library, you can use that definition file as a (partial) basis for understanding how to interface with a particular method. For example, using jQuery with TypeScript in VSCode, typing in `$.ajax` shows you the following information about how it can be used:

  [image]

  You can see something similar for morgan. When hovering over `morgan(` in VSCode, I see:

  ```
  declare function morgan<Request extends http.IncomingMessage = http.IncomingMessage, Response extends http.ServerResponse = http.ServerResponse>(
      format: morgan.FormatFn<Request, Response>,
      options?: morgan.Options<Request, Response>,
  ): Handler<Request, Response>;
  ```

  Then to figure out what `FormatFn` and `Options` may be, I can right click them and select "Go to type definition", and so on. The `Options` interface is:

  ```
  interface Options<Request extends http.IncomingMessage, Response extends http.ServerResponse> {
      /***
       * Buffer duration before writing logs to the stream, defaults to false.
       * When set to true, defaults to 1000 ms.
       * @deprecated
       */
      buffer?: boolean;

      /***
       * Write log line on request instead of response. This means that a
       * requests will be logged even if the server crashes, but data from the
       * response cannot be logged (like the response code).
       */
      immediate?: boolean;

      /***
       * Function to determine if logging is skipped, defaults to false. This
       * function will be called as skip(req, res).
       */
      skip?(req: Request, res: Response): boolean;

      /***
       * Output stream for writing log lines, defaults to process.stdout.
       * @param str
       */
      stream?: StreamOptions;
  }
  ```

  That's very informative!

  Unfortunately, with non-trivial libraries, exhaustively correct type definitions are often dense and hard to understand - but at least they're there.